# Quel est le contraire d'une « erreur par omission » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

J'ai besoin de traduire une phrase en anglais qui pointe les erreurs présentes dans une liste. Elle mentionne des erreurs par omission (« mistakes of omission ») et des erreurs qui correspondent à des éléments qui apparaissent en trop (« mistakes of commission »).

Je ne suis pas sûr que le français propose l'équivalent de « mistakes of commission », en tout cas je ne vois pas du tout de quoi il pourrait s'agir.

Comment: Dans quel contexte ? J'aurais dit « faux positifs » et « faux négatifs », mais en anglais j'aurais dit “false positives” et “false negatives”, donc on ne doit pas avoir l'habitude des mêmes contextes.

Comment: In English, a "mistake of commission" means you do something you shouldn't do, whereas a "mistake of omission" means you don't do something you should do. It's not very idiomatic in English when applied to a list, but I would assume that it means that you put something on the list that you weren't supposed to. But *en trop* in French sounds to me like you put something on the list too many times.

Comment: Une *erreur par ajout* [ *fautif* (erreur causée par l'incompréhension des règles) | *intempestif* (en croyant bien faire) | *irrationnel/incompréhensible* (contraire aux règles/sans règle applicable),  … ] signale une faute d'attention, une connaissance superficielle des règles, une insuffisance intellectuelle …

Comment: Le contexte est une liste de nombres qui est fausse parce que certaines valeurs manquent et d'autres y apparaissent alors qu'elles ne devraient pas.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you, it's exactly what I'm trying to translate. By the way, you can use _en trop_ for something that is present but shouldn't. If you want to specify that the elements on the list are there too many times, you would say _trop de fois_.

Comment: Pourquoi pas simplement mentioner *des valeurs erronées* ?

Comment: La suggestion des _valeurs erronées_ est bonne, et il y a plusieurs autres moyens valables de traduire la phrase, mais ce n'est pas tellement la question en soi. Je me demande s'il y a une expression équivalente à "mistake of commission" en français, avec la même construction, ou si tout simplement s'il n'y en a pas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, I have just translated “errors of commission” with  “**erreurs**” and “errors of omission” with “**omissions**”. I understand that “omission” is a type of mistake and therefore is a subcategory of “erreur”, but generally speaking, when we juxtapose “erreurs” to “omissions”, the former comes to acquire the meaning of “error because you have done something wrong”, whereas “omission” covers the things you have “left out” by mistake (i.e. the opposite). There is also a common legal phrase, “sauf erreur ou omission”, showing that the two terms are used with this particular meaning:

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/sauf/70358

http://www.linternaute.fr/expression/langue-francaise/14389/sauf-erreur-ou-omission/

The two phrases work really well in English because they express contrasting concepts whilst rhyming- in French I was never able to find two phrases carrying the same (precision of) meaning and an effective figure of sound. I know that some translators like to use “**erreurs par action**” vs “**erreurs par omission**” - not sure if it would perfectly fit your context, but it would allow you to keep the rhyme and preserve pretty much the same meaning.